# How to get source code from setup

Tags: windows

I want to to extract source code of a window application, I have only setup.

Is it possible to get the source code from a setup ?

Please suggest some useful tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can't. You cannot retrieve the original source code of a compiled .exe. You **CAN** decompile it, but you'll end up with ugly unreadable code with machine-assigned variable names, and not looking anything at all like the original code.

Answer (score 1):

You can only get the source code from a setup program if the author chose to distribute it. If not then you can download the source from the revision control repository, e.g. sourceforge, github etc. assuming this is an open source project. If not then you should contact the author and request the source.